# REST call returns png, how do i render this?

Tags: java, html, playframework, png

I am testing a REST endpoint using RESTClient, and the content-type of the response is "image/png".  How would I render this content type in html?  I am using java and Play! for my controller, so I have this line:

```
Promise<WS.Response> imagePromise = WS.url(endpoint).get();
```

I am using plain html/css for my view.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data URI scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to display the image. For example, in your JSP/Servlet code:

```
<%
Promise<WS.Response> imagePromise = WS.url(endpoint).get();
InputStream imageStream = // get image stream
String base64Image = // read the stream, and base 64 encode it (you can use Apache commons codec library to do this)
%>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= base64Image %>" />
```